# Sass syntax using 960gs framework

Tags: sass, compass-sass, 960.gs

I'm attempting to  re-learn 960gs using sass syntax.  I am confused on the difference between "+" and "=" sass syntax.  For example:

```
.wrapper
    +grid-container
```

and

```
.wrapper
    @include grid_container
```

would produce the same results in my compiled css file

```
.wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 960px;
}
```

So what is the difference between using "+" and "@include"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No difference at all. Quoting [Sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.INDENTED_SYNTAX.html#mixin_directives):

> Sass supports shorthands for the @mixin and @include directives. Instead of writing @mixin, you can use the character =; instead of writing @include, you can use the character +.